# LOG4j Spring AOP

Tags: java, spring, log4j, aop

I have a j2ee web application running on Spring framework. I want to implement logging using log4j and Spring's AOP. I was trying to find for references but I only get references which does not use log4j.

I had exactly the same configuration as what was on the link you gave. I have declared too a bean which where I want to implement logging. The beans id is ExecuteBLogic so I put below *BLogic

```
<bean name="methodLoggingInterceptor" class="org.developers.blog.spring.aop.logging.MethodLoggingInterceptor"/>
<bean name="proxyCreator" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanNameAutoProxyCreator">
    <property name="beanNames">
        <list>
            <value>*BLogic</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="interceptorNames">
        <list>
            <value>methodLoggingInterceptor</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many examples that show how to log information using spring AOP. The fact that they are using `System.out` or `java.util.logging` should bother you - just replace these lines with log4j lines.

So, ontop of the class:

```
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LoggingInterceptor.class);
```

and then instead of `System.out.println(..)`:

```
logger.info(..);
```

Comment: I added the class MethodLoggingInterceptor  and declared it as interceptor in my application context. I also copy pasted the proxycreator part supplying here the id of my bean

     <property name="beanNames">
             <list>
                 <value>*BLogic</value>
             </list>
     </property>

I didn't change anyhting in the interceptor yet. so I ws expecting a printed log on the console. but i get nothing

Comment: does the logging work in other places? Did you run a debugger to see whether your interceptor is activated?

Comment: i run debugger but it won't enter the interceptor

Comment: then your interceptor is not configured. give your configuration (in your question)

Comment: Your configuration seems ok. The problem would be elsewhere but I can't see. Debug additionally.

Comment: I tried to configure the aop from scratch and it worked. I think I just missed something. Thanks